# How to politely ask a coworker to “Google it”

Tags: professionalism, communication, colleagues

I'm working in a team of 8 consultants just like me. I'm the youngest member of the team and also the one with the least experience (on resume at least). But 4 of the 8 members of the team will often come and ask me questions like:

- Do you know if W3C allows the font tag in HTML5?
- Do we have this CSS class in our stylesheets?
- Do you know what version of IE is the most popular.

All of those questions can be answered by a simple Google (or find) search. Those developers have more than 10 years of experience and some do more than a 100k a year with that job.

How can I politely tell them to stop bothering me with simple questions where the answers can be found easily on Google or with a simple Find command?

I tried to ask "Did you search it?" and the answer is always: I didn't find anything.

Comment: I just respond "I don't know" -Though I would say that telling someone that should not be attempted politely but instead with an air of superiority, and a condescending tone.

Comment: You should really reconsider whether you respond with "google it." Instead, respond in a way that encourages them to get to the problem they want to solve. There may be much more to their issue than the first question you are asked: perhaps there is some implied context that is relevant to the question which googling can't easily address? Perhaps they're trying to develop rapport with you?

Comment: You may find this a little inappropriate, but it's worth a laugh: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=most+popular+version+of+ie.  Depending on how laid back they are, it might do the trick, though (don't do it with people who are too uptight).

Comment: "Do we have this CSS class in our stylesheets?" Seriously? The answer to that is: Do we have a `grep` in our `/usr/bin` that supports `-r`?

Comment: When junior developers do this to me, I will often pull up Google and find the answer while they watch, hoping they will get the hint. I expect the same would work better for seniors above you who will quickly realize they should know better, but YMMV.

Comment: As usual I'm late to the question. Look up coaching. Short version: answer with a question that leads to the answer, in a form that implies they already did it. Eg. "What did it say in the RFC?".

Comment: Require them to bring fresh coffee when they ask you a question.

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't been linked to...While it's not exactly on topic, it's pretty close.... http://xkcd.com/627/

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield and slowly while you explain why you chose the search terms you did... In suitable detail.

Comment: "Let me finish what I'm working on and I'll be over to look at it". 30-60 minutes later go to their desk and if they haven't figured it out yet you can coach them on how to search.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Motion approved, I'm ready for more coffee anytime

Comment: Back in the day before the interwebs, it was RTFM, don't know today's equivalent though.

Comment: @RichardU I was about to say I used to get the RTFM! treatment

Comment: @RichardU - do they still even MAKE manuals?

Comment: @Omegacron I print them out from the online PDFs, no get off my lawn, you darn kids!

Comment: I can relate to this, just not in the workplace. I'm currently helping a friend use multiprocessing in Python 3 and he spent 2 days looking it up while it took me 30 seconds.

Comment: @jqa has it right. The _problem_ is the negative externality: They save 10 minutes, but you lose 20–30 minutes by being interrupted—a loss that doesn’t impact them. The economist’s solution is to internalize the externality by saying “Let me finish what I’m working on and come over” or “Can you give me 20 minutes to finish what I’m working on and come back?” This way, they bear as much of the cost as you. And if it’s _still_ worth it for them to wait 20–30m, maybe, like MilkyWay90 said, they genuinely aren’t sure how to Google it right, and you can help them develop that skill/experience.

Comment: Google is your friend, use it.

Comment: @Kprof I have done this before but only with those I know are able to take a joke and a hint at the same time. Others often get offended.

Answer (score 384, accepted):

When this happens to me I usually ask "what search terms did you try?".  This way if they *did* try to search I might be able to help them search more effectively, and if they *didn't* they sometimes say "ummm..." and go away.

Keeping open the possibility of the first is important; even if I strongly suspect they didn't try I will act as if they did.  That way if they did I don't look bad.

Comment: Which, amusingly enough, is almost what happens when people ask questions on Stack Overflow without having tried anything.

Comment: Wow - I wish I were capable of such tact! :)

Comment: @AdamRackis, it can be learned.  I didn't always respond that way. :-)

Comment: I really love this and do it myself, because you are being helpful without doing any actual work for them. "Try searching for W3C Html5 Font - yeah, that should do it". You can even do it in an email. If they persist that it doesn't work and you want to push the issue, you can bookmark the Google search and be as specific as you want like "the official standard should be at the top" or "I think this is what you were looking for". You have to allow for genuine mistakes, but I find this works great - I say this as the (former) official Googler for my household and old workplace.

Comment: +1. "Show me your search" is my typical answer, or "let me give it a try".

Comment: What I love about this answer is that it assumes good intent but does it in a way that will make them feel bad if there was no good intent. The fact that you ask *what* search terms rather than *if* they searched carries an underlying assumption that the wouldn't *possibly* have come to ask you if they hadn't already Googled... *right*? ;)

Comment: It would be nice if this answer included the possibility of just *answering* them.

Comment: @DCShannon that wouldn't answer the question, nor is it my recommendation.  If you keep doing it for them they'll keep asking; the OP is trying to encourage the asker to try first.

Comment: @MonicaCellio You can do both, and if they ask you so many questions it's detrimental to your work you can go to a supervisor. I find most of the answers on this page to be uncooperative and rude, although this one is better than most.

Comment: @DCShannon if there isn't an answer that covers what you want to say, consider adding an answer of your own.  Just because the OP has accepted an answer doesn't mean more aren't welcome.

Comment: @BrianH +1 for (former) official Googler for my household. My mom is a Googling professional now :)

Comment: I have a coworker. She asked me countless questions. Many are ok questions because it's difficult to google. However, some questions are googleable. I wanted to help her to learn better by asking her to google the question before coming to me. You know what, she reported this problem to my project manager, and I got bad feedback. For some people, you help them 100 times and if only a single time they don't agree with you, they forget your 100 times they got your help. Anyway, I found this answer helpful and will use it next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 85):

I may be interpreting too much here, but of your 3 examples, only one looks to me like it's findable by a simple search ...

- W3C allows HTML5 - yep, that's a fast search... and given the nature of your work, I'd propose stapling W3C to the top of any resource list, putting it out the team in email and a variety of other mass assimilation actions - if you're a web developer, W3C is probably one of your top ranked sites. :)
- Do we have this CSS class in our stylesheets - I don't know how you're going to find that in Google?  It's surely easily searchable in your codebase -- but if your stylesheets are searchable on the internet, you're either working on open source or something pretty wild.
- Do you know what version of IE is most popular - only answerable on the Internet if you're talking about the wide population of "all internet users" or "internet users that hit hugely mainstream sites" - a question of statistics like this has a lot to do with whether the data supports the target user base you are trying to anticipate.  Slant it even a little and you may find a different answer that what "everyone" does.

I point these out, because sometimes it's helpful to consider whether they have other reasons of asking beyond and inability to use Google.  If you have an office where the response is "Google?  never heard of it!" and you do web development... run, run away fast.

Other reasons for asking are:

- they want to know that YOU can think deeply about the problem and come up with more than just a 5-minutes-of-research answer.
- they have a situation where it really IS easier to ask the junior guy - with 12 years of experience myself, I'm so often called into architecture and business meetings that I'm more likely have Outlook and Visio open than any CM tool or SDE - so if you have it open and you have fast access to search our CSS repository, I'm going to ask you to take 5 minutes, when it'll take me 30 to get mine up and started.
- this actually takes some thought and judgement - there may be a correct answer on the Internet, but there may also be 15 "correct" answers, and it'll take some digging to figure out the right one for your team.  They aren't asking for you to a 5 minute task, they want someone intelligent to actually vet the answer.  Google isn't absolute truth, it's a big data index.  If the data is bad, the answer is wrong.
- I don't know it, but I bet you do... - if I think someone knows it literally off the top of their head and can answer me without skipping a beat, I'll ask.  Yep, I could Google it, but Googling takes 10 minutes, asking you on the way by takes 3... I'm asking you.

If you really ARE hitting an epidemic of Answers Best Found on Google - then you may be hitting a senior engineer who is drastically out of touch.  If it's a single individual, ask your own manager what's going on here?  Why is a senior guy asking you for simple answers?  It's interrupting your progress and for no apparent reason.

But if you're getting this from several people, I recommend looking at the trends and seeing why it keeps coming up.  Ask about it, but ask the wholistic question - you see a case where you're asked a lot of simple questions that are easily found on typical web development sites - is there a reason why others aren't finding sucess?

Comment: The CSS part is a simple search function you can access in most applications with Ctrl-F..it's as simple as Google.

Comment: +1 a nice thorough answer as always. All hail the queen of The Workplace!

Comment: 4 senior web developers out of touch it is!

Comment: `if I think someone knows it literally off the top of their head and can answer me without skipping a beat` - Of course the problem is if you are [interrupting somebody in a flow state](http://www.hadermann.be/blog/46/the-hidden-cost-of-interrupting-knowledge-workers/) to save 2-3 minutes, you may be costing him 20-30 minutes to get back into the highly productive flow state. I absolutely hate when my flow gets interrupted, because someone else is trying to save a minute or two.

Comment: @MrJinPengyou Not necessarily - much of the time, CSS is split across a dozen or more files.  But yes, it should just be a `grep` away..

Comment: You guys are too sweet!  But there's plenty of people out there who do better.  Seriously - it rewards my faith in humanity that there are TONS of answers out there that are awesome, made by many many people.

Comment: Agreed on the fact that the search is simple.  But flippantly answering "google it!" for a not-google problem is not the greatest way to make friends.  And realize that while I owned O'Reilly books on sed, awk and grep before HTML 4.0 was a reality... the chances that I can write a decent grep for a CSS class on a day when when I've spent weeks drawing visio and UML diagrams in 20 minutes is a day when we can declare me a Super Genius.  Answering a quick question ain't nothing compared to the context switch of uploading the various command flags of a grep.

Comment: @bethlakshmi - If a senior developer asks such obvious questions, then he/she is surely a FAKE. There is no way a developer with 1 or 2+ years of experience will not google such simple things.

Comment: @Steam: A developer with "1" OR "2+" years of experience is _every_ developer, if my logic unit is right ;)

Comment: @Zoredache In the OP's case, the person who is asked for the answer is the junior though. Some seniors will feel quite justified in interrupting the flow of someone who is beneath their station just so they can stay in theirs. Regardless of my personal thoughts on the issue, there is a case to be made for their point of view: they are seniors after all so presumably their time can be spent in more productive ways than googling trivialities.

Answer (score 27):

You will find that if you give people the answer they will always come back to you. Also telling them LMGTFY is insulting even if it is the obvious answer. It straight out says that they are not worth your time. It also undermines your credibility doing this, as they will think you don't know the answer.

The proper way to deal with this is the GROW model. It is used as a coaching method.

The GROW stands for.

- **Goal**. Establish the goal that they want to achieve.
- **Reality**. Determine the current reality of the situation.
- **Options**. What options can they take to achieve their goals?
- **Way**. What is the way forward from the questions asked?

More details of it here.

http://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/newLDR_89.htm

In short, do not give them the answer, instead ask questions that will lead to the answer they want and help them to direct themselves to that answer.

Examples.

- A1: "What did it say in the W3C specification? If its not in that, what other documentation did you look at?"
- A2: "what style sheets have you examined so far? What pages used those style sheets? Were they overriding the style?"
- A3: "What metric do you want to base it on? Where do you think you could get that metric from?"

You will find that after a while people will only come to you once they have anticipated all your possible questions. Also the GROW model can help find a solution for someone, even if you don't know the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Tell them the Search Keywords to go Google instead of giving them the actual answer, and eventually they'll start going to Google first because they know you'll just send them there anyways.

It's works out quite well for me when people ask for extra help in comments on Stack Overflow, or email me for tech support from my blog. Rather then give them the answer, I tell them something like *If you Google "W3C HTML5 font tag", you should find your answer in one of the top search results*.

It's surprising the number of people that can't Google effectively, and they just need a bit of guidance in how to pick good keywords.

It's kind of like that old proverb:

> Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and
>   you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: Agreed. Google only gives good answers if you ask good questions.

Comment: Just an FYI, [the proverb is arguably not Chinese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach him to use the Internet to find cute cat pictures, and you've ruined his productivity for a lifetime."

Comment: I prefer the version "Build a man a fire and he'll be warm for a day. Set a man on fire and he'll be warm for the rest of his life."

Comment: Give a man an answer and he thinks for a day. Teach him to search the web and show him a cute cat video, and you've ruined his productivity for months.

Comment: This sounds like LMGTFY without actually using lmgtfy.app as a website.

Answer (score 12):

Show them how you find the answer.

I make them watch me type their question into Google, or search the codebase (I ask them to come to my desk, or I walk to theirs). I show them how easy it is and it usually embarrasses them. If it is hard to find, then at least you haven't just told them to go away and try again.

If they lose interest or walk away, don't do anything about it, just ignore it. It's important that they learn how easy it is.

Sometimes they'll just ask you out of convenience, in which case telling them that you're not sure is fine.

Comment: I've done that way frequently without realizing the principle, works well.

Comment: Unfortunately, it only works when people are physically present, not when the work is done remotely.

Answer (score 9):

I don't mind answering most quick questions, if I am not actively focused on a project.

I think the root problem here is that many people forget or are not aware that a 2-3 minute interruption can take 10-30 minutes to recover from depending on how complex the project you are working on is.  Education and communicating this to your peers may help a lot, and you may be able to develop strategies where the understand that an interruption may be far more expensive in time then they saved by using Google/search/grep themselves.

I think many of the suggestions in the article - [The hidden cost of interrupting knowledge workers](http://www.hadermann.be/blog/46/the-hidden-cost-of-interrupting-knowledge-workers/) apply here.

- Have non-urgent questions handled in a non-interruptive way

  - Questions that could have easily be solved by Google or grep fit in this category 95% of the time in my experience.
  - If a person has to wait for you get around to reading/replying to an email, they might just do the search on their own.
- Plan a good time where you can be interrupted.

  - So you can easily deflect these simple questions by saying if it isn't an emergency talk to me a 4:00
- Use Do Not Disturb signals

  - Clearly communicate when you are focused on something to reinforce that you shouldn't be interrupted to save someone 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

### The source of the problem is the negative externality.

They save 10m, but you lose 20–30m when they interrupt your flow—a loss they don’t experience, and therefore don’t think about.

**The economist’s solution is to internalize the externality.** Say *“Let me finish what I’m working on and come over in 20–30m”* or *“Can you give me 20m to finish what I’m working on and come back?”*

This way, they bear as much of the time cost as you. And if it’s *still* worth it for them to wait 20–30m, maybe it’s not so much lack of effort, but they’re genuinely not sure how to start. As MilkyWay90 said in the comments,

> I'm currently helping a friend use multiprocessing in Python 3 and he spent 2 days looking it up while it took me 30 seconds.

This way, you can filter out the low-effort people and (assuming you’re inclined) coach the genuine folk in how to answer their own questions.

Answer (score 5):

I am a software engineer and there is no long, drawn out, overly complex answer required here.

Set the expectation - in the next team meeting, reiterate the complexity of our field and how much of it involves R&D on our own. There is a balance between bothering peers with simple questions and spending 2 days researching something that a team member could have assisted with and saved time. In your case your heavy on the "not spending enough time researching", so make sure to make it clear that everyone should research their own questions **1st** prior to seeking out the help of others.

I have personally dealt with this and sometimes you need to be direct about the response. Don't dance around and find this super crafty way to be overly polite and blow sunshine where it isn't needed. We as engineers are *paid* to research and solve solutions. This is part of our job, period. Junior engineers might need to be told 1 to 2 times and led by example, but on down the road a more direct approach should be used. After all if a software engineer can't Google at least to research a question, do you really want them writing code for a solution you are responsible for? I say no, so help guide these individuals and then add in being very direct about the issue if you have already explained that doing R&D on questions prior to seeking out help is a requirement of the job.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer this on the assumption that something which is true for me, is also true for you; namely, that mentoring is part of your job, regardless of your age in relation to your colleagues.

Whenever this happens I look at it as an opportunity to have a conversation about the topic. (In my experience, that's why they came to ask me instead of looking it up.) As long as I can timebox that conversation to only a minute or two, it's a good way for me to spend some time talking with a colleague about something that interests me.

If they ask something that I don't know, I myself will use Google, while they're at my desk, and we'll have a brief conversation about the results.

Either way, we both win-- my colleague leaves my desk feeling more informed (on my opinions, if nothing else), and I've learned more about my colleague's opinions and experience level, which will come in handy when I need to distribute some of my workload to my colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

If they are simply trying to test you or just checking what you are up to, then as the others mentioned, you can google the problem in front of them and show them the way. However, if they still approach you after even when you deliver your work in time and there is no reason for anyone to check you, then you might have bigger problems in your team.

If senior developers continue to ask you such questions for no logical reason, then they have to be fake. Go to the HR and have their resume and background checked if you haven't done so already.

Its okay  if kids in programming 101 class ask such questions because they are probably not aware of the word `internet forum`. Anyone with 1+ years of experience should know that google helps a lot.

**You should see the movie "I love you phillip morris" which is comedy movie based on a true story. It shows how some folks are good at covering up big lies.**

> Steven cannot bear to be separated from Phillip. After being released, he helps get Phillip freed from prison by posing as a lawyer, then attains wealth by fraudulently acquiring a position as chief financial officer of a large medical management company called USAMM.

[Steven Jay Russell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Jay_Russell)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to ask "Did you search it?" and the answer is always: I didn't
>   find anything

so, perform the search while they stand there watching.

Or, say you will get back to them and email a link form [I Googled That For You](http://igtfy.com/).

After a few of either of those, almost anyone will stop asking. If someone still persists, either say that you don't know, or say that you will get back to them ... and don't.

Answer (score 0):

I've had several answers to this over the years:

A sign on the wall with my "consulting rates" for common questions.

A list of standard answers applicable to many problems. (Accompanied the consulting rate chart as special discounts for standard answers

A list of standard answers to questions in my area of expertise (a FAQ document).

A list of standard places to look for answers to the sorts of questions I was being asked (pointers to other FAQ's and the docs or tools i'd use to answer if I didn't know offhand)

A list of company-internal discussion groups and wiki's and such supported by a community -- better for them because they'll get a wider range of answers sooner, better for me because someone else may answer it before I have to, better for the company since the answers are likely to educate more than one person at a time.

If those don't solve the problem, they can get in the problem queue and  wait until I can get to them... or go back to the consulting fee chart.

Answer (score 0):

### There's an opportunity here

I only ask for info from team members whose opinions I value. Coworkers routinely looking to you for answers indicates that they consider you knowledgeable and respect your advice. This is a good position to be in. There's an opportunity here for you to build a reputation as a highly knowledgeable member of the team. That can get you noticed in a good way.

### How to avoid doing their work for them

But there are times when your coworkers are just wasting your time or taking advantage of you. In this case, you have options:

1. **Send a link to Google search results**. This gives the hint that they could have spent 10 seconds searching for this info themselves. The link to Google search results sends the message that they could have looked it up themselves AND that **you're not willing to sort through the results for them**, but you don't actually have to say all that. **The link says it for you.** I doubt they'll keep asking you if you do this a few times.
2. Reply that you're really busy and **give them a clue for where to look on their own** (e.g. "I'm sorry I don't have time to look myself, but I'm really swamped. I recommend taking a quick look at the style sheet). They may come back to you asking what to search for, which is another tactic to get you to do their work for them. If I suggested that my team member look at the style sheet themselves and they replied and asked me what to search for, I'd probably make a joke and say, "I don't envy you having to search through that mess. Sorry I can't help you out."
3. Ignore the request. Obviously don't ignore a request from a manager, but if you have a lazy team member who is wasting your time, just don't respond. You don't owe them work that you cannot directly bill to a project and you have a responsibility to the client and the project to use your time efficiently. If the team member follows up, send a quick reply that you're too swamped to look right now. I recommend using a joking tone if possible and if appropriate (e.g. "I'm close to solving an error and I'm afraid if I take my eyes off the code I'll never find my way out of this never-ending IF Condition.")

Answer (score 0):

> How can I politely tell them to stop bothering me with simple questions where the answers can be found easily on Google or with a simple Find command?

They're asking you because they think you might already know the answer, not because they've never used a search engine. So all you need to do is to give a direct, honest answer:

## “I don't know.”

Stop being offended that someone might bother you with a question that they could probably figure out on their own, and start feeling flattered that they consider you to be knowledgeable and reliable enough that they'd accept the answer you give them as correct.

I know how frustrating it can be when people are constantly interrupting you with questions that they could answer themselves, but often the problem with such interruptions is that you feel compelled to stop what you're doing and go track down the answer yourself. Let the 3-word phrase above set you free -- you don't need to provide the answer if you don't know it, and *I don't know* minimizes the impact on whatever you were doing. If by chance you *do* know the answer without having to look it up, then you have a chance to be helpful and probably save your coworker several minutes of digging through search results.

The thing that your more experienced colleagues know that you don't is that it's okay not to know things, and that the team's collective knowledge is always greater than that of any individual member. If you pay attention to how they interact with each other, you might notice them asking each other the same kinds of questions that they ask you. That's just the nature of teamwork. You might find that asking *them* questions instead of finding every answer yourself speeds up your own work.

Answer (score -3):

Do you know the answer off the top of your head?

- Yes? Good. Answer them.
- No? Say you're not sure, ask what they've tried, offer to help.

People ask others for help if they think the other person can help them. If they're asking you for knowledge all the time, it means they think you're knowledgeable. This is good.

If you know off the top of your head, then they made the right move asking you. It's quicker than looking, and they can be more confident in your answer than whatever some random guy on the internet says. Verifying the information you get from a Google search can take a while. Asking someone you trust is much more efficient.

Throughout my career, I've often been asked questions I don't know the answer to, simply because of how often I *do* know the answer to other questions. When I don't know it immediately, the person usually just says "oh, okay", and then tries to figure it out themselves. If they've already tried to figure it out, and need help, then I give it to them. If possible, this will consist of advice on how to find it on their own.

As a manager, this is the advice I would give my employees. Refusing to answer a question to which you know the answer is not only uncooperative, but also rude. If you're spending too much of your time answering simple questions, that's something to mention to your supervisor. It's their job to manage talent.

Answer (score -7):

## Be annoying and condescending

Instead explain to him that knowing how to find information is more important than the information itself and then advise him on tips to do this and encouraging him to try these on his own so that he can become more self-reliant in our age of technological enlightenment.

Make sure to smirk mockingly while doing this.

Continuing to answer his questions while being compliant will only further encourage more questions, enabling the undesired behavior. Being instructive to how to find information will discourage the same behavior.

Your tone of being "grander than thou" will go far to prevent further interaction and interruption.

Being patient and nice is a huge waste of time and my down votes here actually reenforce the effectiveness of going against the grain when appropriate.

**Update** Clearly I'm wining in this one as the answer is the most negative which would mean it would be the most off-putting. :)

Comment: I would be careful to lecture people, but I absolutely agree that you cannot enable them.

Comment: I think this answer is hilarious and holds some truth.  Basically, just make it so the person won't ever want to ask you questions again (or speak to you at all).  You forgot "roll your eyes" though.

Comment: @AdamPlocher you get it man. I don't actually do this but it technically would work. Another one is after anyone makes a point say "Well...[insert counter point]" To lose friends and alienate yourself.

Comment: I can see this as a hilarious way to deal with people outside of work. But as for a professional environment this will just get your fired or left out of all advancements in the company. For this reason I must downvote as the context of the issue is at work.